# what is group table in android?

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

I am writing a mobile project using Titanium. I have a question about the table. I want to show the table in group so I used:

```
style:Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED
```

What about in Android, I can not run the code in Android for sure right? I need to go for a condition to check either the platform is Android or iPhone. Please help me to understand about the these tables. What can I replace with when it goes to Android.

Comment: there is no such thing like group table in android .probably you are looking for alternative UI element , if so provide specific characteristics of it, so that people can help you to get best fit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a close look at the documentation every time you want to use functions/methods/variables.

It says clearly which OS it does support. In this case, only iOS:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle-object

You can target the OS with: `Ti.Platform.Osname`

Also look here: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Platform-module.

> the shortname of the operating system. for example, on an iPhone, will
>   return **iphone**, iPad will return **ipad**, Android will return **android** and
>   Mobile Web will return **mobileweb**